# NaN error equation

Tags: javascript, nan

In this javascript code I try to solve a quadratic equation, I've been working on it for an hour and this should tell me the value of a, b and c where y is a(x^2). I'm a relative javascript beginner and would love some help. Why are the values of a, b and c not numbers? The variable names are in italian, in english and in something else(Not even I know what), but I commented what they are. That's one of my bad traits as a student that usually works alone, sorry if it's not easy to understand.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var equa=prompt("Scrivi l'equazione senza spazi usando x come incognita e y come x^2");
        var a = 0.0; b = 0.0; c = 0.0;//ax2+bx+c
        var prima = true; //before or after equal?
        var ope = 1;//1add 2sub 3mul 4div
        var lasto = 0.0;//last number, used for div and mul
        var lastos = 3; //1a2b3c
        var errore=0;//is something messed up?
        for(var i = 0; i < equa.length;i=i){
            if(equa.charAt(i)=='='){
                prima = false;
                i++;
            }else if(equa.charAt(i)=='+'){
                ope=1;
                i++;
            }else if(equa.charAt(i)=='-'){
                ope=2;
                i++;
            }else if(equa.charAt(i)=='*'){
                ope=3;
                i++;
            }else if(equa.charAt(i)=='/'){
                ope=4;
                i++;
            }else{
                var nume = "";//Current number in string form
                while(i<equa.length && equa.charAt(i)>'0' && equa.charAt(i)<'9'){
                    nume+=equa.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                }
                var lasnum = 0.0;//current number in float form 
                var lasval = 3; //1a2b3c
                if(equa.charAt(i) == 'x'){
                    lasnum=parseFloat(nume);
                    lasval = 2;
                }else if(equa.charAt(i) == 'y'){
                    lasnum=parseFloat(nume);
                    lasval = 1;
                }else{
                    lasnum = parseFloat(nume);
                    lasval=3;
                }
                i++;
                if( (ope == 1 || ope == 2) && !(equa.charAt(i) =='*' || equa.charAt(i) == '/')){
                    if(lasval == 1){
                        if(prima) a+=lasnum;
                        else a-=lasnum;
                    }
                    else if(lasval == 2){
                        if(prima) b+=lasnum;
                        else b-=lasnum;
                    }
                    else {
                        if(prima) c+=lasnum;
                        else c-=lasnum;
                    }
                }else if( (ope==1 || ope == 2) && (equa.charAt(i) =='*' || equa.charAt(i) == '/')){
                    //zitto e fermo
                    lasto=lasnum;
                    lastos=lasval;
                }else if( (ope==3||ope == 4)){
                    if(ope==3){
                        if(lastos==3){
                            lasnum*=lasto;
                        }
                        if(lastos == 2){

                            if(lastval==3){
                                lasnum*=lasto;
                                lastval=2;
                            }
                            if(lastval==2){
                                lasnum*=lasto;
                                lastval=1;
                            }
                            if(lastval==1){
                                errore=1;
                            }

                        }
                        if(lastos == 1){
                            if(lastval == 3){
                                lasnum*=lasto;
                                lastval=1;
                            }else{
                                errore=1;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if(ope == 4){
                        if(lastos == 1){

                            if(lastval==3){
                                lasnum/=lasto;
                                lastval=1;
                            }
                            if(lastval==2){
                                lasnum/=lasto;
                                lastval=2;
                            }
                            if(lastval==1){
                                lasnum/=lasto;
                                lastval=3;
                            }

                        }
                        if(lastos == 2){
                            if(lastval==1){
                                errore=1;
                            }
                            if(lastval==2){
                                lasnum/=lasto;
                                lastval=3;
                            }
                            if(lastval==3){
                                lasnum/=lasto;
                                lastval=2;
                            }

                    }
                        if(lastos == 3){
                            if(lastval==3){
                                lasnum/=lasto;
                            }else{
                                errore=1;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    if(equa.charAt(i) =='*' || equa.charAt(i) == '/'){
                        lasto=lasnum;
                        lasto=lasval;
                    }else{
                        if(lasval == 1){
                            if(prima) a+=lasnum;
                            else a-=lasnum;
                        }
                        else if(lasval == 2){
                            if(prima) b+=lasnum;
                            else b-=lasnum;
                        }
                        else {
                            if(prima) c+=lasnum;
                            else c-=lasnum;
                        }
                        lasto=0;
                        lastos=3;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if(errore==0){
            alert("a ="+a+" b="+b+" c="+c);
        }else{
            alert("AOOOOOOo");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: For those wondering, the translation is "Write the equation without spaces using x and y as unknown as x ^ 2"

Comment: Should have translated that as well yes, it's actually "Write the equation without spaces using x as unknown and y as x^2

Comment: What format should the input be? Should the user input "15y+3x+5=20" for example?

Comment: Where (what row) is the error, or what should we input to generate it?

Comment: Yes, the code probably has more flaws than the NaN, one of them I already fixed after uploading this code but it's a simple sign flaw that will never give NaN so it's not important.

Comment: it works well for me with: "15y+3x+5=8" as input

Comment: You input an equation and right now it should only output what x^2 is, what x is and what the known number is.

Comment: Oh yes, right, you ALWAYS have to put a number, even if it's 1, not x, 1x. It doesn't give NaN as much now but it still does so at times.

Answer (score 0):

Since the expected input should be in the format "15y+3x+5=20" for example, then this is a simple regular expression:

```
var equa = prompt("Scrivi l'equazione senza spazi usando x come incognita e y come x^2");
var regex = /^([0-9.]+)y\+([0-9.]+)x\+([0-9.]+)=([0-9.]+)$/;
var matches = regex.exec(equa);
if (matches) {
  var a = parseFloat(matches[1]);
  var b = parseFloat(matches[2]);
  var c = parseFloat(matches[3]) - parseFloat(matches[4]);
  var discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;
  if (discriminant < 0) {
    alert('No real solutions');
  }
  else {
    var root = Math.sqrt(discriminant);
    alert('Root: ' + ((-b + root)/(2*a)) + ', ' + ((-b - root)/(2*a)));
  }
}
else {
  alert("AOOOOOOo");
}
```